# Is there any way to send the realtime data to JBOSS

Tags: java, events, jboss, real-time

I have a system which contains the data of the employee and this system has exposed many web-services and RMI through which any other system can request for data. Now I have a web application hosted on JBOSS. Here the problem is, now I want to get the data from the system to JBOSS in real-time fashion. Though that system has sevral webservice and RMI services through which JBOSS/web-applications can request data but that is on-demand. I looking for a way thorugh which if there is any change in the system, JBOSS get notify at that moment. One solution to it is, I should make process which will call the webservice to know if there is any change in the employee data within a time-interval. What is the other way to notify the JBOSS in real-time?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have a job/separate process which polls your employee application periodically, and sends "data has changed events" to JBoss using JMS.

In JBoss you could have a *message driven bean (MDB)* whichs listens to these events, and stores them in a database.

Another possibility is to have this job running in JBoss which just stores the events/results in memory (search for Quartz, for example have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-quartz/jboss-quartz-tutorial)).

Comment: Thanks Beryllium, I new to J2EE and don't knowledge about many frameworks/tools of Java.